# Search sql query when the number of where statements are variable

Tags: sql, ms-access

I haven't used access in a few years, but I am trying to create a search form  where users can input search criteria in 8 different textboxes and then search based on how many boxes have data. Instead of trying to create a sql statement for every combination I have tried to create one sql statement that would work, but haven't found anything yet.

I have tried using a '*' for every blank textbox which did not work. I am using a variable for every column and thought I could use a empty string for the empty textbox columns but then I do not know which one would be the last and how to make the last variable not have an "AND" behind it. I could loop through the variables, but is there an easier way?

Here is my code as it is now...

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim frm As Form, rs As Recordset
Dim nb As String, cs As String, s As String, ss As String
Dim od As String, cd As String, t As String, tt As String, st As String
Dim sql_select As String, sql_from As String, sql_where As String

If IsNull(Me.txtNumb) Then nb = "" Else nb = "nc.[NC Number] = """ & Me.txtNumb & """"
If IsNull(Me.txtCS) Then cs = "" Else cs = "nc.[CS_Build] = """ & Me.txtCS & """"
If IsNull(Me.cbSection) Then s = "" Else s = "nc.[Section] = """ & Me.cbSection & """"
If IsNull(Me.cbSubSection) Then ss = "" Else ss = "nc.[Sub-Section] = """ & Me.cbSubSection & """"
If IsNull(Me.txtOpenDate) Then od = "" Else od = "nc.[Date_Open] = """ & Me.txtOpenDate & """"
If IsNull(Me.txtClosedDate) Then cd = "" Else cd = "nc.[Date_Closed] = """ & Me.txtClosedDate & """"
If IsNull(Me.cbTPS) Then t = "" Else t = "nc.[TPS] = """ & Me.cbTPS & """"
If IsNull(Me.cbTPStype) Then tt = "" Else tt = "nc.[TPS_Type] = """ & Me.cbTPStype & """"
If IsNull(Me.cbStatus) Then st = "" Else st = "nc.[Status] = """ & Me.cbStatus & """"

sql_select = "SELECT nc.[NC Number], nc.[Date_Open], nc.[CS_Build], nc.[Section], nc.[Sub-Section], nc.[Status], nc.[Date_Closed], nc.[Notes] "
sql_from = sql_query + "FROM nc "
sql_where = sql_query + "WHERE " & nb & " And " & od & " And " & cs & " And " & s & " And " & st & " And " & cd & " And " & ss & " And " & t & " And " & tt & ";"

Me.lstSearch.RowSource = sql_select + sql_from + sql_where

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this. I'm not sure it is a good way. I replaced the empty string "" when the textbox is empty with something that is always true like "1=1". That allowed the query to be executed.

But is there a better way?